# "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" in xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I am trying to create a struct in my data files that can be used in another class in my project. I keep receiving the error message "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). Additionally it tells me there is 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 in my main method in the data.m file. I crawled through some solution pages on here and tried all the solutions listed, such as making sure there is not import of a .m file, changing the Enable Bitcode to No, checking that there is no duplicate files, and removing -ObjC from Other Linker Flags. I am fairly new to Objective-c so I think it may be something wrong with how I am declaring the struct.

```
//data.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface data : NSObject   

typedef struct Cards
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* Name;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* Images;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* Phone;
    __unsafe_unretained NSMutableAttributedString* Website;
    int   Restaurant_id;
}Card;

@property Card* ExampleCard;
@end

//data.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "data.h"


@implementation data
@synthesize ExampleCard;
@end
int main( )
{
    Card Salernos;
    Card *ExampleCard;   // = malloc(sizeof(struct Cards) * 16);

    /* Salernos Restaurant specification */
    Salernos.Name = @"P. Salerno's III";
    Salernos.Images = @"Salernos";
    Salernos.Phone = @"(609) 245-0474";
    Salernos.Website = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Order Now!"];//yourTextView.attributedText = str;
    [Salernos.Website addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"https://www.grubhub.com/restaurant/p-salernos-iii-1292-lower-ferry-rd-ewing/313805?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=place%20action%20link" range: NSMakeRange(0, Salernos.Website.length)];
    ExampleCard[0] = Salernos;

    return 0;
}
```

In the class that I would like to use the data from the struct I put

```
#import "data.h"

...
data *Data;
```

The data that I wish to use is written as Data.ExampleCard[i] where i is apart of a for loop that retrieves the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are implementing main method. Main method is automatically implemented by system.

`You should implement`init`method in your .m file instead of`main` something like,

```
 -(instancetype)init{

self = [super init];

if (self) {
    Card Salernos;
    Card *ExampleCard    = malloc(sizeof(struct Cards) * 16);

    /* Salernos Restaurant specification */
    Salernos.Name = @"P. Salerno's III";
    Salernos.Images = @"Salernos";
    Salernos.Phone = @"(609) 245-0474";
    Salernos.Website = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Order Now!"];//yourTextView.attributedText = str;
    // [Salernos.Website addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"https://www.grubhub.com/restaurant/p-salernos-iii-1292-lower-ferry-rd-ewing/313805?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=place%20action%20link" range: NSMakeRange(0, Salernos.Website.length)];
    ExampleCard[0] = Salernos;



}
return self;
}
```

Comment: I think this will work for me, it got rid of the error message so far. Would I have to change the data *Data line in my other class?

Comment: You should alloc and init it!